# Why does the clear() function not get called when the onChange event occurs?

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm completing an exercise on Javascript form validation.
In my code, I have a table with three columns: form name, form, validation message.
When an error occurs during form validation, the message appears in the third column. When the form element is changed -the error message should disappear but it doesn't. It seems the clear() function isn't called at all. Could someone please help me out - thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Validation</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clear()
    {
        for(var i in document.getElementsByName("error"))
        {
            document.getElementsByName("error")[i].innerHTML = "";
        }
    }


    function validate()
    {
        if(document.Form.Name.value.length < 1)
        {
            document.getElementsByName("error")[0].innerHTML = "Please enter your full name."
            return false;
        }

        if(document.Form.Address.value.length<3)
        {
            document.getElementsByName("error")[1].innerHTML = "Please enter full address."
            return false;
        }

        if(document.Form.Phone.value.length <6)
        {
            document.getElementsByName("error")[2].innerHTML = "Please enter a phone number."
            return false;
        }

        if(document.Form.Email.value.length <5 || "@".search(document.Form.Email.value)==-1)
        {
            document.getElementsByName("error")[3].innerHTML = "Please enter a valid e-mail address";
            return false;
        }

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Validation</h1>
<p>Enter the following information. When you press the Submit button, the data you entered will be validated.</p>
<form name="Form" onSubmit="return validate()">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Name" size="20" onchange="clear()" class="Form"></td>
    <td><div name="error"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td><textarea rows="5" columns="20" class="Form" onchange="clear()" name="Address"></textarea></td>
    <td><div name="error"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Phone" onchange="clear()" size="11" class="Form"></td>
    <td><div name="error"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>E-mail</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Email" onchange="clear()" size="20" class="Form"></td>
    <td><div name="error"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
<input type="button" value="Clear" onClick="clear();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try renaming the clear-method to something else (e.g. "clearErrors"). Seems that there is some name-conflict with built-in functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <html>
    <head>
<title>Validation</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Validation</h1>
<p>Enter the following information. When you press the Submit button, the data you entered will be validated.</p>
<form name="Form" onSubmit="return validate()">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Name" size="20" onkeypress="return clearErrors();" class="Form"></td>
    <td><div name="error"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td><textarea rows="5" columns="20" class="Form" onkeypress="return clearErrors();" name="Address"></textarea></td>
    <td><div name="error"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Phone" onkeypress="return clearErrors();" size="11" class="Form"></td>
    <td><div name="error"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>E-mail</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Email" onkeypress="return clearErrors();" size="20" class="Form"></td>
    <td><div name="error"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
<input type="button" value="Clear" onClick="return clearErrors();">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearErrors()
        { 

            var arr = new Array(); 
            arr = document.getElementsByName('error'); 
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
                document.getElementsByName('error')[i].innerHTML = "";

            }      
        return true;
    }


    function validate()
    {
        if(document.Form.Name.value.length < 1)
        {
            document.getElementsByName("error")[0].innerHTML = "Please enter your full name."
            return false;
        }

        if(document.Form.Address.value.length<3)
        {
            document.getElementsByName("error")[1].innerHTML = "Please enter full address."
            return false;
        }

        if(document.Form.Phone.value.length <6)
        {
            document.getElementsByName("error")[2].innerHTML = "Please enter a phone number."
            return false;
        }

        if(document.Form.Email.value.length <5 || "@".search(document.Form.Email.value)==-1)
        {
            document.getElementsByName("error")[3].innerHTML = "Please enter a valid e-mail address";
            return false;
        }

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```